# What to do when UX survey respond rates are close to each other?

Tags: surveys

I've asked the following question:

"You've found an activity you like on our website. Which one of statements below would make you more likely to inquire about this activity."

1. This activity is selling out fast!
2. This activity is very popular!
3. This activity is trending!

Results are pretty close:
43%
38%
35%

How to analyze this? How much difference do I need in order to pick a winning option?

Answer (score 1):

Such questions I would avoid because these riggers are based at our visceral level and we are not really aware of what "ticks" for us. This would be a job for A/B testing than surveys. While some people may have the ability to explain why they booked an apartment many don't realise that they were pushed into it by a statement like: "this place will be fully booked soon" and even if they realise it they would like to tell you that they booked it because it looked good and had a good price.

Comment: To support your reasoning, not only are we barely aware of what actually influenced us when we made a decision, but in the case of a hypothetical question like above, the difference between what we imagine doing and what we do is enormous. The reliability of the answers for this question is close to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The poll you've conducted is a great start but the results are fairly close. I think this is a great opportunity for you to do some A/B/C testing.  A multivariate testing enables you to direct 33% of your users to each of the three options and allows you to assess conversion rate.  The winning option with the highest conversion rate can inform you which option to use for 100% of the users.